# Why isn't VS Code providing any IntelliSense or syntax highlighting for my file in a programming language?

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am creating a project in React with Tailwind.

When I create a CSS file, it is recognized as a .css file (as the icon indicates), but in the file it is impossible to have anything, everything remains "hard" (no effect on my project, autocompletion etc...)

My css is well linked on the html (even if it doesn't come from that it seems)

It's the first time I have this problem, does anyone have an idea?

I tried to check all my projects or something on chatGPT, even on stackoverflow.

Comment: Perhaps a theme issue? what if you try changing theme? what theme are you using right now? Or perhaps an extension issue? Try doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) or restarting with extensions disabled.

Comment: Tried to uninstall, disconnect my account, with bisect but still not ...

Comment: what about changing your theme? And you still didn't say what theme you're using. So when doing an extension bisect there was never any different at any point? Please respond clearly to each question. What do you mean by "disconnecting your account"?

Comment: I found it ! i wasnt using a specific theme (basic one). But for an unknown reason, the file was in plain text instead of css

Answer (score 0):

It's not visible from your screenshot, but the [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) has probably been changed to something that isn't CSS, and indeed it was confirmed by the asker that it was set to "Plain Text". The indicator of the language mode is at the bottom right of the screen.

You can [change the language mode for a file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_change-the-language-for-the-selected-file) by clicking that indicator, or using the `Change Language Mode` command in the command palette.

If the issue happens again after a restart of VS Code, I'd also check if you have any `files.association` settings that are causing the problem to persist, and adjust those rules as necessary to fix the issue.